# Customize Eclipse CDT to use Ratliff style for auto formatting

Tags: eclipse-cdt, code-formatting

How to customize Eclipse CDT to use Ratliff style for auto formatting?

[Ratliff Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Ratliff_style) of formating code indents the terminating brace to the same level as the contents of the block:

```
 for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     if (i % 2 == 0) {
         doSomething(i);
         }
     else {
          doSomethingElse(i);
         }
     }
```

Eclipse CDT allows a number of common styles to be selected for auto formatting. Ratliff is not in the list but you can modify them to meet your specific requirements:

[image: Eclipse CDT Formatter Edit]

except there is no option in the list of choices to have the end brace align with the block contents:

[image: Options for braaces]

Answer (score 1):

No one has implemented this option in CDT's formatter.

CDT is open source, you're welcome to [contribute a patch](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Getting_started_with_CDT_development) that implements it.

However, given how little CDT's formatter is maintained in general these days, a better use of your time might be to contribute support for the Ratcliff style to [clang-format](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) (which also doesn't currently support it, as far as I can tell), and use clang-format in CDT via a plugin like [CppStyle](http://www.cppstyle.com/).